# R.java doesn't have map for R.id.map

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps, google-api

So I'm following [this](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) guide TO THE LETTER (or at least trying to).

And aside from having to import some things not specified in the guide, everything is fine EXCEPT there is a red squiggle that I can't explain.

In this line:

```
GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)  getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
```

there is a red mark under "map" in "R.id.map".

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.*;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment)      getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

I have already included android-support-v4.jar my buildpath and I have downloaded everything correctly from the Google SDK (including Google Play services). I have an API key too. Apparently it should be working by now.

Comment: What does your red squiggle say, when you click it? Are you sure that you have 'map' id in your activity_main.xml layout file?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me that Step 7 is the one where your missing resource comes from:

> Update res/layout/activity_main.xml and replace the entire contents
>   with

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:id="@+id/map"  android:layout_width="match_parent" 
 android:layout_height="match_parent" 
 class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```

In Eclipse you need to:

1. Change the file
2. Save it
3. Clean your project (to regenerate the resoureces, among them R.java)

Answer (score 1):

If u have `android:id="@+id/activity_main"` instead of `android:id="@+id/map"` in the activity_main.xml. This error is probable.

I got the similar error.I replaced

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```

to

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MapsActivity" />
```