# Map cannot be resolved: is not a field on (R.id.map)

Tags: android, android-maps-v2, supportmapfragment, mapfragment

I am a beginner in Android programming. I have an error on the project MapFragment. Even though they had followed the tutorials on Google. I've imported the Google library project and play service on my eclipse. Is there anything that can help?

map cannot be resolved is not a field

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    GoogleMap map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.**map**)).getMap();
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [R.java doesn't have map for R.id.map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16348982/r-java-doesnt-have-map-for-r-id-map)

Answer (score 0):

Never change your R.java manually, it is generated by the Android compiling process, from you XML files. Do you have a UI XML file containing a `MapFragment`, and is this `MapFragment` named `map`?

For an introduction to building UIs, read [Building a Simple User Interface](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html). An example of a named control can be found at [this header](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html#TextInput).

Good luck!